# How to run GUI application without monitor

Tags: server, ssh, xorg, desktop-environments, vnc

I have an ubuntu server with Nvidia GTX 660. I initially used ubuntu-server but later installed LXQT (not sure if it is required). I want to start java application with ssh without connecting any monitor. The application requires display. Previously I had similar projects where I used VNC in VPS (without GPU) to achieve that result and it used to work fine. But right now I have dedicated GPU and want to use it so I am not sure how to configure everything so that I would not waste any resources and use full potential.

I was able to start the application using ssh while I have my monitor connected and user logged in on lxqt. The moment I logged out of the desktop (server) everything stopped working and was not able to start the application using ssh.

**Update:** Want to make the situation more clear. It only works if I have one account logged in physically using GUI and then I can start programs using SSH too. If the GUI is closed the program doesn't start over SSH. Using screen on SSH doesn't help because I close the GUI session too. I want to be able to do everything without logging in physically over GUI ever.

Comment: Use a terminal multiplexer on the server to keep your login session alive after disconnecting. Two of the most popular are `screen` and `tmux`. Both are in the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: It only works if I have one account logged in physically using GUI and then I can start programs using SSH too. If the GUI is closed the program doesn't start over SSH. Using screen on SSH doesn't help because I close the GUI session too. I want to be able to do everything without logging in physically over GUI ever.

Answer (score 0):

Question is unclear because you say you need X11, but maybe you just need program to keep running after you log out.

If your program needs X11, Xvrb is a program that 'fakes' presence of X11 server. We use that to run firefox in scripts in systems that do not have  X11.

On other hand, if program quits when you log out, there are many fixes. A program like screen can create terminal sessions that run when you log out. If you tell us more about about problem program,  we might help.

Comment: I may not use the name X11 correctly. Sorry. Update: It only works if I have one account logged in physically using GUI and then I can start programs using SSH too. If the GUI is closed the program doesn't start over SSH. Using screen on SSH doesn't help because I close the GUI session too. I want to be able to do everything without logging in physically over GUI ever.